# Minification failed. Returning unminified contents. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am running into an issue when using minification in an ASP.NET MVC application using .NET 4.6.2..

I am getting this

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(5228,6): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';'
(5229,10): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';'
(5425,28-36): run-time error JS1009: Expected '}': function
(5338,31): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';'
(5425,37-38): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5426,37-39): run-time error JS1006: Expected ')': =>
(5426,36): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';'
(5427,33): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';'
(5431,10-11): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: )
(5433,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5434,29): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';'
(5434,39-40): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5435,37-39): run-time error JS1006: Expected ')': =>
(5435,36): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';'
(5436,33): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';'
(5439,10-11): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: )
(5440,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5441,31-32): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5462,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5463,32-33): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5470,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5471,33-34): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5482,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5483,31-32): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5498,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5499,31-32): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5514,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5515,32-33): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5521,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5522,33-34): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5533,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5534,34-35): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5764,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5765,57-58): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5775,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5776,57-58): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5786,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5787,33-34): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5816,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5817,40-41): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(5856,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(5857,33-34): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(6115,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(6116,31-32): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(6177,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ,
(6178,45-46): run-time error JS1010: Expected identifier: (
(6337,1-2): run-time error JS1002: Syntax error: }
 */
```

When I go to one of those lines, it brings me to a function that looks like this

```
ActivateVendees: async function (idList) {
    idList.forEach(async (e, i) => {
        const vendee = await this.GetVendorsImplementorByImpID(e);
        vendee.Active = true;
        this.SaveImplementor(vendee);
    });
},
```

that code is namespaced, thats why it looks like that...Is there anything that stands out from that function on why it might cause minification issues? from the looks of things in that error script that it does not like namespacing...

Comment: Whatever the minimizer you're using is, it does not support modern JavaScript syntax (`async`, arrow functions, ...).

Comment: @AKX, thats odd because you would think that Visual Studio 2019 would be supporting this, I am just using the one that comes with VS2019...do you recommend any other minifier?

Comment: By reading from other posts, it seems that is not related to visual studio version, but the version of the Web.Optimization library, which dates back to 2014(last release) and doesn't support newer ECMAScript versions.